# I can't access the download page of the spring framework

Tags: spring, jar

I am trying to access the download page https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/release/org/springframework/spring/ , but I ALWAYS get 404 error using VPN and different computers. Since no one seems to have problems accessing the page I am going insane right now. Can you guys access the page and what problem could cause a 404 error on my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is wrong and that's the reason it responds with 404. In my computer is a 404 also without using any kind of VPN.

[image]

Try locating what you want manualy from the [base path](https://repo.spring.io/ui), although what I think that you need is [here](https://repo.spring.io/ui/builds/spring-framework?buildRepo=artifactory-build-info)